# Jtools- error message-no applicable method for 'summ' applied to an object of class "list"

Tags: r, survey

I am using jtools in survey data, and I am trying to summarize the regression model as below and I am able to fit the model but can not use summ() function to get the results using jtool package. I am using the dateset to use other survey package related analysis and works well.

```
fit_a<- svyglm(DIED ~ conanomalies ,  design=TET_svy, family=quasibinomial(link=logit))
summ(fit_a)
```

I get an error message

```
"Error in UseMethod("summ") : no applicable method for 'summ' applied to an object of class "list".
```

Could someone please suggest how to get over this error. Thanks.

Comment: i'm not able to reproduce your error, could you construct a minimal reproducible example using the examples found at the bottom of `?svyglm`  ?    i'm unclear how `fit_a` has a `list` class when `svyglm` always returns a `svyglm` class object.  `jtools::summ` does have a `svyglm` method so i believe this should work..

Comment: Thanks. I just now did the same in Rstudio server and I did not get the error message. Probably, some issues with R version in my computer.